# What is OpenId URL for a account

Tags: openid

What is my OpenId URL

EG: [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/account/signup/) wants me to signup using my OpenId URL. I want to use Google just like i use in SuperUser but there is no obvious link to Click on just a textbox for OpenId URL

Comment: Go through the comments in http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2008/10/google-moves-towards-single-sign-on.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the OpenID URL displayed by stackoverflow is either incorrect or Bitbucket handles it incorrectly. What you have to do is to take that URL and strip off the query string, i.e. the '?' and everything after it.

For me the resulting URL is **`www.google.com/accounts/o8/id`** (not sure if the o8 part is the same for everyone).

It then seems to work correctly

Comment: It's the same for me.

Comment: only "www.google.com/accounts/o8/id" is required?

Comment: Highlight the answer(the url)

Comment: yes o8 is the same for everyone

Comment: There are shortcuts like http://bit.ly/gopenid and http://tinyurl.com/googop (and probably many others; make sure to use one that will not be redirected to some phissing site in the future).  But all is still for *if you feel really geeky*, according to Google at http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2008/10/moving-another-step-closer-to-single.html (And if you own a Google blog, then you can use that URL for a less secure OpenID 1.1 as well.)

Comment: @Arjan "...make sure to use one that will not be redirected to some phissing site in the future" - thanks for that tip. So, use the official url or, for convenience, use an url shortening service that you have vetted using a time machine. ;o)

Comment: Interesting to me that they never implemented the 'gmail.com' openID provider.  5+ years later and still have to use the 'geeky' url.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it from  your Superuser profile page. It's between "Seen" and "Website".

If I goto the BitBucket site (via your link) and enter my OpenID pasted from my profile it takes me to the [myOpenID](http://www.myopenid.com) (my OpenID provider) sign in page. This is the same page I get for any site. If I enter my password I get access to the site.

**Apparently this doesn't work with the Google OpenID as displayed in your profile**

*I'm not in a position to take a screen shot at the moment*

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: That is the first thing i tried, its not working for my google account

Comment: @Rishi - There's something different about the way Google handles OpenID. It caused Jeff & Co problems with these sites. There's at least a couple of questions over on meta.stackoverflow.com about this.

Comment: Wait, i tried it again, the url was getting clipped in SU page, hopefully it should work now

Comment: Nope, still does'nt work, What openid provider are you using

Comment: I'm using myOpenID (www.myopenid.com) I switched when Jeff first mentioned problems with Google. I keep Google as a backup

Comment: Try using a Yahoo! OpenId if you have a Yahoo! account.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, but i registered the normal way, damn you google

Comment: As I said in one of the comments from my deleted answer Googles OpenID implementation is extremely weird.

Comment: Mention "does not work with google in your answer", Better give a new answer with openid.com as an alternative, is there a non profit alternative?

Comment: Try MyOpenId.  I think that OpenId provider is great!

Comment: @ephilip Describe the greatness in a answer

Comment: @Rishi, @ephilip - if you notice I already mention I'm using myOpenID.

Comment: your answer is half correct, add the info

Comment: @Rishi, I guess that if you would have added "Google" to the title of your question, then your comments upon all the answers would not have been necessary.